# Difference between Gilbert Strang's "Introduction to Linear Algebra" and his "Linear Algebra and Its Applications"?

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request

Could someone please explain the difference between Gilbert Strang's "Introduction to Linear Algebra" and his "Linear Algebra and Its Applications"? Thank you.

Comment: Please don't do successive edits and rollbacks.

Comment: In my memory, the former lesson didn't show too many applications besides Fibonacci numbers, high order linear ODEs, etc.

Comment: I got another answer from Ronyee from OpenStudy (MIT 18.06 Linear Algebra, Spring 2010): "I think Introduction to Linear Algebra tells us the crucial concept of Linear Algebra. Actually it has some applications but It's like a textbook. But Linear Algebra and its application is more concentrating on adapting Linear Algebra to solve a problem we faced! Conclusion: Textbook -> Adapting to solve problem in reality or supporting some engineering concepts!"

Answer (score 12):

Quoting an answer on Quora:

> *Introduction to Linear Algebra* is a more introductory book, whereas *Linear Algebra and Its Applications* assumes that the reader is already familiar with the basics of matrices and vectors.  *Introduction to Linear Algebra* also seems to have some material introducing the abstract view of linear algebra, whereas *Linear Algebra and Its Applications* looks like it's mostly focusing on material that's relevant for engineering applications.